# Delete dynamic div element and child after ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm new in jquery and ajax and im working at datatables last time, but then i tried to display my items using the div to got a better view but then i'm having hard time to delete the div element after ajax success.

by the way im using mvc5 of asp.net

Please help me and Advance thank you to all of you

If you guys have suggestion or revision of my code to more easy approach, please let me know.

This is my div element. I looped through the model by foreach loop so my div is dynamic.

```
    <div id="div_table" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            @foreach (var food in Model)
            {

//I want to delete this div after success

                <div id="@food.food_ID" class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="thumbnail" style="height:150px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            @food.foodName
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <button class="btn-sm btn-info">Edit</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <button class="btn-sm btn-danger btn-js-delete" data-customer-id="@food.food_ID">Delete</button>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                count++;
                if (count == 4)
                {
                    count = 0;
                    @Html.Raw("</div>")@:<div class="row" style="margin-top: 30px">
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

My jquery ajax.

```
 @section scripts{
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#div_table").on("click", ".btn-js-delete", function () {
                    var button = $(this);

                    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the selected food", function (result){
                        if (result)
                        {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "/AdminFood/Delete/" + button.attr("data-customer-id"),
                                success: function () {
                                    button.parent("div").remove();
                                    debugger
//I dont know how to implement in div
                                    $("#" + button.attr("data-customer-id")).remove(); 
                                    bootbox.alert("Food Successfully Deleted");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootBox-js")
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html. Use class names and relative selectors instead

Answer (score 1):

`button.parent('div')` will get the first parent, and that's not what you want.

I would put some class in the div you want to remove, for example 'deletable'

```
<div id="@food.food_ID" class="col-lg-3 deletable">
```

then instead of `button.parent('div')` you do something like this:

```
button.closest('div.deletable')
```